# Problems with Booting “red hat”. disk volumes issue

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, network-attached-storage

I recently installed the Red Hat 6 OS on HP proliant server. This server has 8 1TB drives. I created  two volumes RAID 5 each having four hard drives (and 2.7TB). On one of the volumes, I installed the operating system while creating three logical volumes (the swap 8GB, 50GB of the root mounted on "/" and 2.6TB of home mounted on "/ home"). With the other volume, I created a logical volume of 2.7TB and I mounted it on "/données". Everything seemed to work until I rebooted my server this morning and I got the following errors :

```
  Welcome to Red Hat Enterprise linux Server
Démarrage de udev :                                     [OK]
Configuration du nom d'hôte db-oracle-node1.albatres.red[OK]
Primary GPT is invalid, using alternate GPT. 
Configuration du gestionnaire de volume logique : 3 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_albatres" now active
                                                        [OK]
Vérification des systèmes de fichiers
/dev/mapper/vg_albatres-lv_root : propre, 85787/3276800 fichier, 835757/13107200 blocs
/dev/sda1 : propre, 39/120016 fichiers, 56422/512000 blocs
fsck.ext4: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type lors de la tentative d'ouverture de /dev/mapper/vg_donnees-LogVo100
/dev/mapper/vg_donnees-LogVo100:
Le superbloc n'a pu être lu ou ne contient pas un système de fichier 
ext2 correct. Si le périphérique est valide et qu'il contient réellement 
un système de fichier ext2 (et non pas de type swap, ufs ou autre),
alors le superbloc est corromppu, et vous pourriez tenter d'exécuter 
e2fsck avec un autre superbloc :
    e2fsck -b 8193 <périphérique>

/dev/mapper/vg_albatres-lv_home : propre, 31/179314688 fichiers, 11306290/717254656 blocs
                                                       [ECHOUE]

*** Une erreur s'est produite pendant la vérification du système de fichiers
*** Vous connecte à un shell ; le système va redémarrer
*** lorsque vous quittez le shell.
*** Attention -- SELinux est actif
*** Désactivation du niveau de sécurité pour la restauration du système.
*** Lancer << setenforce 1 >> pour réactiver
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue:
```

so, the shell appears. even if I run the "startx" command, it doesn't work:

```
hostname erreur de répérage du nom de l'hôte cible
/usr/bin/startx: line 160: cannot create temp file for here-document: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement
/usr/bin/startx: line 170: /usr/bin/xauth: Permission non accordée
/usr/bin/startx: line 172: cannot create temp file for here-document: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement
/usr/bin/startx: line 170: /usr/bin/xauth: Permission non accordée
/usr/bin/startx: line 172: cannot create temp file for here-document: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement

Fatal server error:
Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock

(EE)
Please consult the Red Hat, Inc. support
    at https://www.redhat.com/apps/support/
 for help
(EE)
giving up.
xinit: Connection refused (errno 111): unable to connect to X server
xinit: No such process (errno 3): Server error.
/usr/bin/startx: line 197: /usr/bin/xauth: Permission non accordée
```

on the other hand the "df" command that displayed all my discs only displays the root disk 50GB

Comment: Adding an English  translation for the errors would help.

Comment: @DaveM After you've seen enough broken systems, you'll recognize those particular errors in any language.

Answer (score 0):

The shell prompt you received is not a normal system prompt; it's intended for you to fix the problems that prevented a normal boot.

So let us look at the problems.

First, there was an important clue:

```
Primary GPT is invalid, using alternate GPT.
```

This strongly suggests to me that something has overwritten the start of the virtual disk. One of the tools parted or testdisk ought to be able to fix this, once you get the rest of the system up.

---

For the data partition, I think maybe you have simply made a typo somewhere. See this error:

```
fsck.ext4: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type lors de la tentative d'ouverture de /dev/mapper/vg_donnees-LogVo100
```

(in English:)

```
fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open de /dev/mapper/vg_donnees-LogVo100
```

Your LV name specified here seems to be `LogVo100`, but typically this would have been created as `LogVol00`. Notice the difference between the number one (incorrect) and the lowercase l (correct). You should be able to correct this in `/etc/fstab`, and that ought to resolve that problem.